# Binding technology to use for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, binding

I am a novice iOS app developer. Basically i need to listen for any change in the UI (e.g., doing something on text change in textviewUI), and update UI to reflect any model change.  I was looking into different technologies available for binding and am bit overwhelmed.

I know this is very subjective, but i would like to hear your suggestions on it (for swift and objective c both)

Also any pointers to the best practices would be really helpful.

Comment: The delegate methods of `UITextField` (or `UITextView`) provide callbacks for text change events in these fields. These are the callbacks iOS provides to make your bindings, any fancier solutions will probably be a wrapper around these.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to iOS! `Cocoa` (Touch for iOS)- Apple's framework- has some design patterns you will want to learn...
These include `delegation` and `target/ action`. Quickly summarized: delegation is handing some responsibilities off to an object that can take care of them. This provides methods you can use to get stuff (like changes) to that object. Read this link to learn more about delegates: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/
Now, back to the text field example. A handy method in the `UITextField` delegate called `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` will be called whenever the text field is going to change. As for target/ action, that's google-able. Is that a word? As for any pointers, learn MVC. Have fun!